# How can i change my h2 title to <p> text while keeping size and alignment?

Tags: html, css, title

I want to change my `<h2>` text to `<p>`. But I want it to look the same as the `<h2>` text.

I've tried changing my CSS to no avail:

```
        <section id="" class="form container-fluid">
        <form id="frm_contact" action="" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data" style="">
            <h2>Make an Enquiry</h2>
            <p>Make an Enquiry</p>                                                                          
            <p>Please ask us about any parts you need and we’ll get back to you shortly.</p>
```

The text just comes back obviously as standard p text, but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to change the code.

I want 'Make an Enquiry' (what is currently h2) to be `<p>`, but still look the same.

[image]

[Have a look at what i mean here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oIAv.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please edit the code block to correct the mistakes (among other things missing the quote before the `enctype` attribute-value, as well as the white-space *in* that attribute-value.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers display `<h2>` with these default values [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp) :

```
h2 {
   display: block;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   margin-top: 0.83em;
   margin-bottom: 0.83em;
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

So, your best bet is to add a class to the `<p>` element with the above properties.

HTML

```
<p class="text-mod">Make an Enquiry</p>
```

CSS

```
 .text-mod{ 
          display: block;
          font-size: 1.5em;
          margin-top: 0.83em;
          margin-bottom: 0.83em;
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 0;
          font-weight: bold; 
        }
```

EDIT:
Okay, since the above solution didn't work, it must be because of specificity.

Try overriding the properties using !important:

```
 .text-mod{ display: block !important;
            font-size: 1.5em !important;
            margin: 0.83em 0 !important;
            font-weight: bold !important;
          }
```

Note: Using !important is an extreme measure and is only recommended when nothing else works out.

Comment: And what does this code *do*? How does it work? What problem does it correct? What can anyone to learn from these blocks of unexplained code?

Comment: @DavidThomas Is it better now?

Comment: Same thing, it's not recognizing this CSS. Still same small text

Comment: @jacksonpearce_ Must have something to do with specificity; There is always !important as the last resource.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the tag to `<p>`, and use CSS styling to change the way it appears.

For example you could do:

```
<p class="headingText"> Make an Enquiry </p>
```

And in your CSS file:

```
.headingText {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 14px;
     }
```

You can learn more about CSS here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/

If this doesn't answer your question please let me know how I can help you :)

ADD TO CSS FILE:

```
.makeHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#000;
  text-transform: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Have tag like so:

```
<p class="makeHeader">Make an Enquiry</p>
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter where i put it in my CSS should it? It's not working.

Comment: Make sure you're importing the css file in the HTML template. I recommend you put a class or id on each element and style it appropriately. If you upload your project to an online resource such as code pen i could fix it and send the code example back to you with a fix.

Comment: Try this! Thanks Christopher https://codepen.io/jacksonpearce_/pen/dBNLmJ

Comment: Check the answer it has been updated =). Also i'd also like to say you really shouldn't be overriding basic HTML like <p> and <h1> you should be adding classes or id's to elements to change their appearance.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes I've only been trying to change the CSS. To increase my SEO I want to only have relevant headers, that's what Google looks for. Hence changing the h2 to p.

Comment: BUT, I tried using that and playing around with it. NO LUCK. Which is a bummer, any other ideas?

Comment: I would troubleshoot this by first removing the specificity to see if thats the issue. ( remove all hard coded styling on native HTML elements e.g <p>, <h2> ) and add classes instead. Try doing this then let me know of the result! Also the class i asked you to add, make sure thats at the bottom of your CSS file as it could be getting overridden by other styling.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I tried my global.css & style.css all hard coded styling and it didn't work. And there isn't any hard code on it. Did I mention that it is for a contact form (.php) that is added into all pages on my website. Having that knowledge, would there be anything else that would affect it?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I mean't the overwritten HTML element styles e.g <p> and <h1> should be removed. I understand you're doing this for SEO however it makes it pretty hard pinpoint the issue. If you've already tried this try removing styles from your CSS one by one and seeing if it affects your element. If you have a class on the <p> you want to look like H1 and have the styling I've mentioned above, It should do what you want it to when you remove the troublesome code. I can't tell if it's the PHP without seeing the code. You can post it if you like and i'll have a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the inline CSS to overwrite some changes.

```
<section id="" class="form container-fluid">
    <form id="frm_contact" action="" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data" style="">
        <h2>Make an Enquiry</h2>
        <p style="font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;">Make an Enquiry</p>                                                                          
        <p>Please ask us about any parts you need and we’ll get back to you shortly.</p>
```

You can always change the styling if you wanted to by using this kind of approach.